# I can not move an azure website from one subscription to another

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

We have 2 azure subscriptions old and new.

I can not use the resource move button to push the app service **mysite.azurewebsites.net** from the old subscription to the new subscription.

That would be too easy! The subscriptions are from **different people/companies** so the **old** subscription is not aware of the **new** subscription in the user interface of azure portal.

Now I have 2 questions:

1.) Is there any way to still move the app service although they do not share the same **tenant**? - I guess its called like that - Can I make both subscriptions to have the **same tenant**?

2.) I assume here that I have to **re-create** the app service and copy/paste all appsettings and that option 1.) will not work! But doing that I can not create the app service with the same name **mysite.azurewebsites.net** because its already in use in the old subscription and site names must be unique in the whole azure system. (too bad that production app does not use a certificate... *rolleyes*)

How will number 2. work then? I really need that name because many other websites already use it...

Comment: Create a support call

Answer (score 1):

> 1.) Is there any way to still move the app service although they do not share the same tenant? - I guess its called like that - Can I make
>   both subscriptions to have the same tenant?

Unfortunately, it's not possible to do that. One tenant can have different subscriptions, but one subscription can only in one tenant(Azure Active Directory). So, If your another subscription has belonged to another tenant, you cannot share it with your this tenant.

> How will number 2. work then?

Yes, you need to recreate your App service. If you want to use the old App name for your new App , you need to delete the old Web App. Because Azure doesn't allow two Web Apps have a same App name.

Hope this helps!

---

**Update**

There are two another ways to achieve that.

1. Redirect the old web app's URL to the new web app .This can be done by configure your web app itself.
2. a. You can back up your old app to a storage account.

   b. Delete your old web App.

   c. Download the backup files to your local machine.

   d. Go to another subscription and upload the backup file to a storage account.

   e. Restore the old app from the storage account.

These ideas are inspired by the OP-[@Elisabeth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/320460/elisabeth). Thanks!

---

Update 2

Unfortunately, my test result is failed. When I selected the ZIP file from a storage account to restore the app, it just did not respond at all. It can restore it by app back up. But from the storage account, it did not succeed .

Comment: What if I would create a app service with a new name. Create a redirect on the old app service to the new TESTED app service. Delete the old app service and SOMEHOW rename the new service to the old app service name is that somehow possible?

Comment: Or is it possible to make a backup of the old app service and apply it to the new app service?

Comment: HI,@Elisabeth . It's a good  idea. However, it's hard to say that  it's whether possible to redirect the old app to the new app. Maybe this can be configured by your old app itself. As I known, Adding a CNAME records of the old app's name  on new app  is not possible .  The back up of the old app and apply it to the new app service is quite a greater idea. 1.You can back up your old app to a storage account. 2. Download the backup files to your local machine. 3. Go to another subscription and upload the backup file to a storage account. 4. Restore the old app  from the storage account.

Comment: @Elisabeth . I did not test this solution , but I think it should work!

Comment: redirect from oldsite.azurewebsites.net to newsite.azurewebsites.net should not be a problem and when the backup old site + upload it to new site works (before I guess I have to delete the old site) because on uploading the new site the old site with the name should not exists.

Comment: @Elisabeth , Yeah, you got it. cheers! Since it's a great idea, i will update my answer and add the idea so that  we can help more people. You can accept it as an answer, thanks!

Comment: I will create next week quickly 2 test sites and try the above plan wether it work or not I let you know :-)

Comment: Hi, @Elisabeth , May I know that have you resolved your issue?

Comment: Sure. I got another user story... the subscription stuff is postponed, but I will try to make tomorrow a quick test with  2 test sites etc... and let you know.

Comment: Sorry Wayne, could not test anything and we will not do the subscription change, the owner of the subscription will do it ;-)

Comment: Hi,@Elisabeth. I have two subscriptions now. I will do a test and keep you updated if I have any process.

Comment: @Elisabeth . Unfortunately, my test result is failed. When I selected the ZIP file from a storage account to restore the app, it just did not respond at all.  It can restore it by app back up. But from the storage account, I did not succeed .